# Creating API via Cloudformation fails with "Body cannot be specified together with BodyS3Location" (TITLE CHANGED)

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an API Gateway via Cloudformation, with the API defined using Swagger, since I had some problems (see below) setting it up as just Cloudformation resources.

Here's the chunk of my Cloudformation template that defines the Api (mostly taken from [here](https://blog.jayway.com/2016/09/18/introduction-swagger-cloudformation-api-gateway/)):

```
"Api": {
    "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
    "Properties": {
        "Name": {
            "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                    {
                        "Ref": "paramProjectName"
                    },
                    "_API"
                ]
            ]
        },
        "Description": {
            "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                    "Created by ",
                    {
                        "Ref": "paramScriptName"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        "FailOnWarnings": true,
        "Body": {
            "swagger": "2.0",
            "info": {
                "version": "2016-08-18T18:08:34Z",
                "title": "Slack API"
            },
            "basePath": "/LATEST",
            "schemes": ["https"],
            "paths": {
                "/slack": {
                    "post": {
                        "parameters": [],
                        "produces": ["application/json"],
                        "responses": {
                            "200": {
                                "description": "200 response"
                            }
                        },
                        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                            "uri": {"Fn::Join": ["", [
                                "arn:aws:apigateway:",
                                {"Ref": "AWS::Region"},
                                ":lambda:path/2015/03/31/functions/",
                                {"Fn::GetAtt": ["Lambda", "Arn"]},
                                "/invocations"
                            ]]},
                            "responses": {
                                "default": {
                                    "statusCode": "200"
                                }
                            },
                            "httpMethod": "POST",
                            "type": "aws"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

and here's my buildspec:

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.json --s3-bucket scubbo-slackbot-3-bucket
                                   --output-template-file outputTemplate.yml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - outputTemplate.yml
    - index.py
```

But when I try deploying this with a CloudFormation deploy step of a CodePipeline, it fails with `Body cannot be specified together with BodyS3Location`. I'm confused, because I don't see the string `BodyS3Location` anywhere in my repo. [This](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2320) seems to suggest that, at some time in the past, `BodyS3Location` was created by default, but it *looks* like that bug has been fixed.

Original question below, for context

---

(Original title: 'Cloudformation Api update fails with "Invalid Swagger 2.0 input"')

I'm trying to set up a CodePipeline (via Cloudformation) to pull updates from a GitHub repo and update a Lambda function (mostly guided by [here](https://blog.jayway.com/2016/08/17/introduction-to-cloudformation-for-api-gateway/) and [here](https://github.com/milancermak/lambda-pipeline)).

However, when the final step of the CodePipeline executes, the update to the existing stack fails (at updating the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi`, the first Resource in the template) with `Invalid Swagger 2.0 input`

I suspect (based on results like [this](https://maketips.net/tip/123/solve-invalid-swagger-20-input-when-import-swagger-to-aws-api-gateway) and ivectbor's comment [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=714556)) that this is something to do with the translation from json to yml causing incorrect quotation (single-quote instead of double). However, when I add the option `--use-json` in the `buildspec.yml`, build fails with `Unknown option`. Same if I try `--use-json true` or `--use-json True` (the whole Internet seems to prefer yml to json - I can't find any examples of that usage to copy)

Here's a snippet of the template I'm trying to execute *in* the Deploy step of the CodePipeline:

```
"Api": {
    "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
    "Properties": {
        "Name": {
            "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                    {
                        "Ref": "paramProjectName"
                    },
                    "_API"
                ]
            ]
        },
        "Description": {
            "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                    "Created by ",
                    {
                        "Ref": "paramScriptName"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        "FailOnWarnings": true
    }
}
```

With buildspec:

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.json --s3-bucket {BUCKET-NAME}
                                   --output-template-file outputTemplate.yml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - outputTemplate.yml
    - index.py
```

I can't *guarantee* that this is the same output-template-file that's being used, but the following is the result of running that `aws cloudformation package` command locally:

```
Resources:
  Api:
    Properties:
      Description:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - 'Created by '
          - Ref: paramScriptName
      FailOnWarnings: true
      Name:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - Ref: paramProjectName
          - _API
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
```

which certainly includes `'`'s.

I updated my template to be in YML format (and replaced all `'` with `"`), but still got the "Invalid Swagger 2.0 format" message.

Comment: `the whole Internet seems to prefer yml to json`. Not true. JSON is more readable and way more awesome than yaml.

Comment: I completely agree, but you wouldn't know it from the AWS examples!